# Why are persisted user settings not loaded?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, persistence, settings

I have a windows application that uses an assembly that stores some configuration settings in the default application settings.

The settings can be changed in run time and are persisted thus:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.SelectedCOMPort = options.SelectedCOMPort;
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

The settings are saved correctly and I confirm this by looking at the user.config file saved in the users application directory E.g.

```
C:\Documents and Settings\e399536\Local Settings\Application Data\MyCompany\MyTool
```

However when the tool is closed and then started again all the settings are loaded with their default values.

Checking the user.config file once the application is running confirms that the settings are still as saved.

The settings are loaded thus:

```
options.SelectedCOMPort = Properties.Settings.Default.SelectedCOMPort;
```

Why are the default settings being used and not the saved ones?

Have I missed something??

@ Tenaciouslmpy
The settings are loaded during the constructor of the assembly, which itself is loaded in the form load event of the main assembly.

@ Austin
This is a standalone app that I am debugging in Visual Studio.

Comment: Can you post the code where you are loading the string settings?

Comment: When are you loading the settings? What event in the Form's life-cycle?

Comment: Is this from a stand-alone install or are you running from the IDE?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are recompiling the application between runs, note that it will consider that a new version of the app and will **not** automatically load per-user settings. You need to call Settings.Default.Upgrade in this situation.

One way to do this only when needed is to add a NeedsUpgrade setting (value True) to the application's default per-user settings. On app startup, check if NeedsUpgrade is true. If so, call Upgrade, set NeedsUpgrade to False, and save the settings. The next time the app version changes, NeedsUpgrade will reset to True and you'll auto-call Upgrade to bring in any existing user settings again.

Make sure you're setting NeedsUpgrade **after** calling Upgrade, or it will get wiped out when the settings are upgraded.

```
if (Settings.Default.NeedsUpgrade)
{
    Settings.Default.Upgrade();
    Settings.Default.NeedsUpgrade = false;
    Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

Comment: I'm not recompiling however I am debugging in the IDE which seems to do the same thing. In any case the Upgrade() tip has solved the issue. Cheers.

Comment: I am having that issue with the debug session on the IDE (VS.2015) The settings are reverted to defaults. I implemented the NeedUpgrade hint but the problem persisits.

Comment: I just tested it in VS 2015 Community, and it still works for me. Note that it appears the behavior is a little smarter these days; it won't reset NeedUpgrade to true unless the assembly version changes; just rebuilding the application won't do it any more.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like you're debugging the application from Visual Studio when every time you start a new session you start with the default data.

If you're seeing this with an installed release, then I would guess you're not actually using the string values when you think you are.

Comment: Ah, that would be it, Cheers.