# Windows form UserSettings is not loaded

Tags: c#, winforms, settings

I have create a user setting in my Windows form application named "ExchangeRate" and set it to "1", then the value is being updated at runtime:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.ExchangeRate = 1.5;
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

But when I restart the application the "ExchangeRate" value reset back to "1".

How can I fix this issue to load the value I previously set "1.5" in this case?

Comment: Are you trying this in debug mode? Maybe it is overridden on every run?

Comment: @MatthiasKoch: Yes I'm in debug mode, what can I do then?

Comment: @mann: I'm just guessing, but you can try to start the application through the explorer.

Comment: @MatthiasKoch: It doesn't work. I also try [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201819/why-are-persisted-user-settings-not-loaded) but no luck :(

Comment: User settings are stored in %user%\AppData\Local afaik. Try to find the user.config. Maybe it is a permission problem.

Comment: I'm not near VS so I can't test what I'm saying, but have you tried `Properties.Settings.ExchangeRate = 1.5; Properties.Settings.ExchangeRate.Save();`? I think you might not want to touch the `Default`, that would be to return to it's inicial value, created in design-time. Give it a go and I'll test it later as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have to synchronize your settings every time you change.

If you have changed a value just checked whether it has been changed in the app.config file which will be like your applicationname.exe.config