# C# Properties.Settings.Default not remembered on system reboot

Tags: c#, .net, settings

I know there are similar questions here already on stack overflow, and I have already explored these before asking this question.

I have a C# program, and I am storing about 7 string settings.
The program saves the settings fine - you can open and close the application as much as your like and its fine. But, when you reboot the operating system, or logout and back in, and restart the program all of the settings are gone.

This is not restricted to my environment, I have tested on 3 different machines and and still getting the same error.

I have explored my issue here on stackoverflow; [Why are persisted user settings not loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201819/why-are-persisted-user-settings-not-loaded)

And I have also tried the `Properties.Settings.Default.Upgrade();` and this does not fix my issues either.

Does anyone have and ideas as to where I am going wrong?

Comment: you would need to provide more information - what do you exactly do when your program starts to read the settings? does the folder Users/<user>/AppData/Local/<company_name> and it's subfolders stay there after reboot or it disappears?

Comment: The file and folder stays there. Fine. When the program launches within the code each setting is called, e/g  string mailaddress = Properties.Settings.Default.emailAddress;

Comment: how do you run your program? do you start the compiled exe from your disk or from visual studio?

Comment: Its a compiled exe, published from the click once publisher built into VS2012

Comment: one more thing that comes to my mind - if you save your settings and "lose" them after reboot - the values remain in the user.config file, right? what happens if you start the application after reboot and you save settings all over again, are they written to the same xml file replacing the old values or is the new user.config created?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the error was due to using ClickOnce deployment. 
The software was creating similar to a Temp version on each launch and not communicating to the settings.
Used nullsoft installer, to install the raw .exe and now works perfect!